# Probability about random couples and their height difference

Tags: probability

So I was given a chart with heights, one column with the father's and the other with the son's.

These are the questions I have to answer, and I was able to work out all of them except the seventh:

Calculate all the coefficients necessary to obtain the regression lines.

¿What height would you predict for a son whose father is 175cm?

¿What is the probability that the former prediction is off by 3cm?

Of the fathers that are taller than average, ¿what is the probability that his sons are shorter than average?

What percentage of sons are at least 5cm taller that their fathers?

The difference in height of two friends is 10cm, What do you predict is the different in height between their fathers?

Five random friend couples are chosen. What is the probability that at least three of those couples have a difference in height of 5cm or greater?

I am struggling to figure out the last question, how to calculate the probability. The questions are translated, so maybe some are difficult to understand. I put the former questions to give an idea of what I have already done, and maybe it can be used for the question.

Answer (score 1):

With the last question, notice that you can express a probability $p$ that any individual father-son pair has a height difference of greater than 5cm. And if you pick five such pairs independently, then each of them has that same probability $p$ (if you know nothing about the heights of the individuals involved), and that those probabilities are independent of each other.

In other words, you are taking 5 independent trials and looking for an event that has probability $p$, and asking for the probability that the event happens at least three times. Does that sound like another probability distribution you might be aware of?

Comment: Yes, I was just trying to solve this using binomial distibution, but I had trouble fining p(the probability of succes in one trial), p would be p(|x-y|>5), but while I was trying to solve this probability I got stuck.

Comment: That probability is the probability of "x-y > 5 OR y-x > 5", where those are mutually exclusive probabilities. Do you know how to work with those?

Comment: No I think I don't. As I said, I tried working it out, but i got stuck. I worked with the standar ddeviation and μ(they cancelled each other out), but I couldn get to any results. Just to clarifiy, the "friends" are pairs of people taken from the group of sons.